# the same high-performance hardware **as is the case** for single- and double-precision arithmetic.** meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Microprocessors in the x86 family historically implemented all floating-point operations with a special 80-bit (10-byte) floating-point format (see Problem 2.86). This format can be specified in C programs using the declaration long double. We recommend against using this format, however.
> It is not portable to other classes of machines and **it is typically
> not implemented with the same high-performance hardware **as is the case** for
> single- and double-precision arithmetic.**

--Computer Systems:A Programmer’s Perspective 3rd edition

I'm not sure the last line's meaning after "it is typically..."

So the "long double" type can't be as effective in other machines as single- and double-precision types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the "long double" type can't be as effective in other machines as single- and double-precision types?

Yes, exactly that. The other machines have to 'work around' this format and do so in a way that is less effective (perhaps drastically less effective, but the text doesn't say that) than old x86 machines.